# Switch DOMAINS (from .com to .ca) keeping product URL the same

Tags: html

I have a switcher on my site that switches users from Canadian to US site, but the problem that it is only switches to the homepage's of the respective sites.

The issue is that when you are viewing  the product on Canadian site let say: mycanadiansite.ca/hats/baseball-caps, and then decide to switch to .COM., it brings you back to the homepage of mycanadiansite.COM. Both of my sites have exactly the same product URL's, so just switching the domain will work fine.

What should I add to my current switcher code, so upon a website switch the urls past the domain name "/hats/baseball-caps" are remain in the URL field, only domain changes.

```
href="http://mycanadiansite. ca/" target="_self"><span>cad site</span></a></p>
```

Comment: how are your pages generated?

Comment: They are shopify based., both sides are Identical to each other, with same urls.

Comment: do you have any access to the server side code?

Comment: I have access only to HTML files. This is the switch I have on my US site which will send customers to Canadian website.

Comment: href="http://mycanadiansite. ca/" target="_self">cad site..... but as you can see it sends to Homepage, but I would like to keep /path the same as on US website.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with a bit of JavaScript.

1. Select all the link tags that you want changed.
2. Set parse the `href` attribute - stripping out the authority part.
3. Update the `href` attribute with the new authority.

Comment: Thank you, will give it a shot.
 You think there is any easier way to  tell the browser during switch only change .ca or .com part of the URL, without actually changing the url as a whole?

Comment: @Icon no. that is a different origin so the security policies apply. it might be best to see if you can use a subdomain so that you can have the cookies at your main domain.

Comment: What do you think about integrating
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.location.href = "http://" + "here-your-target-domain" + window.location.pathname
</script>

Comment: that will force the redirect.